# Read Timed Out Error in reading URL using java

Tags: java, url

I have return a code to read a web page using jsoup-1.7.3.jar, Its working for some websites but giviing Read timed out error for some of the URls....
.

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed
>   out   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
>     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:443)
>     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
>     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
>     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)     at
>   Main.main(Main.java:10)

Comment: ... and what happens if you try going to one of these urls with your browser (or curl)?

Comment: @millhouse::using curl or browser they never gave me error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [ooxi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2534648/ooxi) mentioned, you can set a timeout

```
Jsoup.connect("").timeout(5*1000).get() //which sets timeout for 5 seconds
```

**Edit:** You can specify the timeout though the Connection

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("");
connection.timeout(5*1000); // which sets timeout for 5 seconds
```

Comment: Again it gave me same error immediately after just clicking on run even after adding timeout(5*1000)

Comment: @AnkitKumar may be code sample can help in resolving the error

Comment: in my case, I added `.userAgent("Opera")` option and solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `.get` you can set a timeout for example

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
```

Have a look at the JavaDocs of [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html) and [Connection](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html)